# how to convert date field to specific timezone?

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, timezone, datetime-format

I am facing problem in converting date from US time to Indian Standard Time(IST)
because my server timezone is as per US time zone and India is **12:30** hour ahead from us ..

ex. in US today **20-03-2015 4:05:17** 
And in India **2015-03-20 16:35:17**

My Database Field is dateOfBirth

```
select DateOfBirth from student
```

Output:

```
1992-09-18
1992-03-20
```

but when i am adding +12:30 hour to my field it is working

```
select switchoffset(CAST(DateOfBirth as datetimeoffset),'+12:30') from Student
```

OutPut

```
1992-09-18 08:00:00.0000000 +08:00
2015-03-20 08:00:00.0000000 +08:00
```

i wrote this query for display birthdate of those persons who are having birthday today.

```
select dateofbirth from student where (dateofbirth = (switchoffset(CAST(GETDATE() as datetimeoffset),'+12:30')))
```

but comparison with today's date is not working.
anyone have solution ..?
please help me

thank you..

Comment: This should be done in application logic, not in the database.  SQL Server has very limited time zone support, and cannot handle things like daylight saving time without significant effort.

Answer (score 1):

The **year** of student birthdat not be selected just day and month

this code return a VARCHAR MMDD

```
declare @monthDay VARCHAR(4) =  RIGHT('0'+cast(month(switchoffset(CAST(GETDATE() as datetimeoffset),'+12:30')) as VARCHAR(2)) ,2) +  RIGHT('0'+cast(DAY(switchoffset(CAST(GETDATE() as datetimeoffset),'+12:30')) as VARCHAR(2)) ,2)
```

Comment: thankyou for comment.. but my project is working correctly and display birthday with this query
`SelectCommand="SELECT   MiddleName,Surname FROM Student WHERE (DATEPART(d, DateOfBirth) = DATEPART(d, GETDATE())) AND (DATEPART(m, DateOfBirth) = DATEPART(m, GETDATE()))">`
but when i upload on server it detects server time( located in US) and results change asa per server time..

Comment: @VivekDesai May be use the GETUTCDATE() for work with date. [GETUTCDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-EN/library/ms178635.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You've this in your query:
    dateofbirth = (switchoffset(CAST(GETDATE() as datetimeoffset)
which makes sql to look for exact match of date of birth i.e. if switchoffset returns 24-03-2015 05:55:06 +12.30 (hypothetical), then dob needs be equal to this, which is impossible. try to put this in a range, something like this:

```
DECLARE @resultAfterUsingSwitch AS DATETIMEOFFSET;
SELECT @resultAfterUsingSwitch = switchoffset(CAST(GETDATE() as   datetimeoffset),'+12:30');
DECLARE @range1 DATETIME, @range2 DATETIME;
SELECT @range1 = CONVERT(Date, @resultAfterUsingSwitch) 
SELECT @range2 = DATEADD(dd, 1, @range1)
select dateofbirth from student where dateofbirth>=@range1 AND dateofbirth<@range2
```